# cannot set colors css tornadofx

Tags: css, kotlin, tornadofx

I am just playing with examples of TornadoFX, but I cannot reproduce the following https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx/wiki/Type-Safe-CSS, more precisely:

```
backgroundColor += hoverColor
```

Doesn't compile for me, it says `type mismatch, required Paint, found CSSRule`
Neither can I set the `borderColor +=box(dangerColor)`, I also have a type mismatch
[image: type mismatches picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your imports are wrong, try using the

```
import tornadofx.*
```

statement. Currently, you are using `tornadofx.Stylesheet.Companion.box` function, instead of the `box` function from `CSSKt.class`.

Comment: Thank you, indeed, I was importing both `import tornadofx.* ;
import tornadofx.CssRule.Companion.c`, and removing the second solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your exact code and it compiles and works. Either you're using an outdated version of TornadoFX or you have some other error in your file that confuses IDEA to give you the wrong error message. Try for yourself with this exact snippet and you'll see that it compiles:

```
class Styles : Stylesheet() {
    companion object {
        val dangerColor = c("#a94442")
        val hoverColor = c("#d49942")
    }

    init {
        root {
            button {
                backgroundColor += Color.GRAY
                borderWidth += box(5.px)
                borderColor += box(dangerColor)
                and(hover) {
                    backgroundColor += hoverColor
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On another note: Why do you wrap everything in `root`? There should be no need for that.

Comment: This says exactly the same type mismatch error... I should consider upgrading IDEA right

Comment: well, no now I have the latest IDEA build, and tornadofx is 1.7.14 :(

Comment: Then post your complete class, you have something in there that trips the compiler.

Comment: @EdvinSyse, I got the same problem, and I suspect it is raised by the `c` function, `borderColor +=  box(Color.GRAY)` works, I have this property in my class `val borderColor = c("#333333")`, and the only import is `import tornadofx.*`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use two builtin functions

1. c()     //pass color string and opacity as parameters
2. multi() // pass string color